# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named cant figure out why

Tags: django

going to retrieve a simple httpresponse from view at nested app, but some how having this error which cant figure out what the problem.

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
# from .corex import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('corex.urls')),
]
```

app[corex] urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.testcorex, name='testcorex'),
]
```

app views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def testcorex(request):
    return HttpResponse('module passed')
```

traceback error

```
File "/home/differentmonster/App/x_house_project/x_house_backend/x_house_cms/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    path('', include('corex.urls')),
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/x-house-cms-p6EwdKv_-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corex
```

the installedApp should be no problem cause, if i import corex.views directly into root urls.py, the response works. but after i added the url.py into app, the module cant be found. and i am using poetry for venveniroment and django 3.0.6.

thanks guys

Comment: your file names should be `urls.py` not `url.py`

Comment: @mahyar oh yeah i named it right, i just mistype here, thanks for correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Firsteval, you should check if `corex` is in your INSTALLED_APPS in you settings.py.

Next, be careful about your file name, you are calling `corex.urls`, but in your post, you name your file `url.py` (without the plural).

Comment: Yeah the INSTALLED_APPS is confirm is inside and the named it right with the urls.py, i miss type here :D, thanks for correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figure out the problem came from structuralize folder.

```
x_house_project[level_1]

-x_house_project[level_2]

  --corex[level_3]
  --urls.py
  --views.py

-urls.py
-settings.py

manage.py
```

in root urls, if i change the corex into x_house_project/corex, things are good, but i cant figure it out the django logical, cause if the settings.py INSTALLED_APPS already setup the path and the logic run from root urls.py, isit more weird putting in the folder path x_house_project ?